# Can Only .click Once

Tags: javascript, jquery

http://jsfiddle.net/cwUcM/

I've gone through all of the other threads that seems to have a similar title, but I haven't found anything =(

I added a console.log, which also only fired after the first click.

It should be a fairly simple issue.

Why is the event only being fired after the first click?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're only calling the `if` statement on the first load.

After that, the click events have already been registered to only do one thing. Move the `.click` handler outside the `if` statement.

See: http://jsfiddle.net/SQxYP/

Comment: I will be accepting this answer as soon as I can (couple more minutes ^^) thanks a bunch!

Answer (score 3):

The `if` condition should be inside the `click` handler. Try this.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#menu').click(function() {
        if($("#openCloseIdentifier").is(":visible")){
            $("#menu").animate({
                marginTop: "2%"
            }, 500);
            $("#openCloseIdentifier").hide();
        }
        else{
            $("#menu").animate({
                marginLeft: "5%"
            }, 500);
            $("#openCloseIdentifier").show();
        }
    });
});
```

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/cwUcM/4/)**

Comment: I appreciate your response, unfortunately you were 9 seconds too slow =( I will still upvote whenever I can =)

Answer (score 1):

Additional clicks work, you just don't see the result.

```
$("#menu").animate({
     marginTop: "2%"
}, 500);
```

Change to:

```
$("#menu").animate({
      marginTop: "+=2%"  <--- you need at ADD 2%, not set it to 2%!
}, 500);
```

Comment: Didn't answer the question I had, as it was an issue with having the .click event after the if statement. Although, this response did answer another question I was going to have eventually, so thanks!